# KeyPressEventArgs does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows.Input' (are you missing an assembly reference?) Windows Phone 2012 SDK C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-sdk

I am having a bug with my coding and it is really starting to get hard around

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using Business_Card.Resources;
using Windows;
using Microsoft;


namespace Business_Card
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
            //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        }

        private void TextBox_TextChanged_1(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void TextBox_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyPressEventArgs e)    
        {

            string[] nums = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "-" };

            if (!nums.Contains(e.KeyChar.ToString()))

                e.Handled = true;

        }
    }
}
```

That is the full class

But here is the part with the error

```
    private void TextBox_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyPressEventArgs e)    
    {

        string[] nums = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "-" };

        if (!nums.Contains(e.KeyChar.ToString()))

            e.Handled = true;

    }
```

Specificly the line

```
private void TextBox_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyPressEventArgs e)
```

The part where it says **System.Windows.Input.KeyPressEventArgs** it is telling me that the namespace or name isn't found in **System.Windows.Input**

I have also tried doing **using System.Windows.Forms;** It says Forms isn't found either and I did go the the references and it wasn't found there.

Comment: That's Winforms code.  In WinRT you use the TextInput event.

Comment: It says it's an event but its used as a type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `KeyDown` event.

```
private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

     string[] nums = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "-" };
     if (!nums.Contains(e.Key.ToString()))
     e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: No didn't work, The main problem is the KeyEventArgs it can't find it

Comment: How you registering your event ? Try by selecting textbox from designer and then form properteis window. Select events buttons and scroll to key down event and double click on it. May designer itself solve this problem

Comment: i just added at the top **using Windows.UI.Core;** it fixed the KeyEventArgs but now i have another problem the Key in
**if (!nums.Contains(e.Key,ToSting()))** says this error **No deffinition found in Windows.UI.Core**

Comment: Then check by e. and see which function are there supported by keyevent.